# how to store the same index value of few arrays in another single array

Tags: java, arrays

import java.util.Scanner;

public class namefinder {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("                        NAME PREDICTER        ");

    System.out.println(" Row 1  A B C D E F");
    System.out.println(" Row 2  G H I J K L");
    System.out.println(" Row 3  M N O P Q R");
    System.out.println(" Row 4  S T U V W X");
    System.out.println(" Row 5  Y Z . . . .");
    System.out.println("enter the length of your first name in number!!! EX: vino , so length is 4");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int y =  scanner.nextInt();
    int s[] =  new int [20];


    for(int i=1;i<=y;i++)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter whether the "+i+"letter of your name is in which row");
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    s[i] =  scanner1.nextInt();
    }

    char a[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    char b[] = {'G','H','I','J','K','L'};
    char c[] = {'M','N','O','P','Q','R'};
    char d[] = {'S','T','U','V','W','X'};
    char e[] = {'Y','Z','.','.','.','.'};


  for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
      for(int j = 0; j <=y; j++) {


          switch(s[j] ) {  // Since counting starts from 0.

          case 1: System.out.print("\t"+a[i]);break;
          case 2: System.out.print("\t"+b[i]); break;
          case 3: System.out.print("\t"+c[i]); break;
          case 4: System.out.print("\t"+d[i]); break;
          case 5: try {

              System.out.print("\t"+e[i]);
          } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {

              System.out.println("\t "); // Print an empty space with a \t character. 
          }

          break; // Prone to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                    }
  }
  System.out.println(" "+"Row"+ (i+1)); // Print a newline character after printing every line
```

}

---

output:
                        NAME PREDICTER
 Row 1  A B C D E F
 Row 2  G H I J K L
 Row 3  M N O P Q R
 Row 4  S T U V W X
 Row 5  Y Z . . . .
enter the length of your first name in number!!! EX: vino , so length is 4
3
Enter whether the 1letter of your name is in which row
4
Enter whether the 2letter of your name is in which row
2
Enter whether the 3letter of your name is in which row
3
    S   G   M Row1
    T   H   N Row2
    U   I   O Row3
    V   J   P Row4
    W   K   Q Row5

### X   L   R Row6

Help Needed:
Now i need to store all the alphabets which is row 1 in to seperate array.
I.e row1[] = {S,G,M} and row2[] ={T,H,N} and so on...........

Comment: What your asking for is a 'transpose' method for a 2D array. As far as I know, Java doesn't have a method for that readily available, but writing one yourself should be easy. Create a new 2D array and fill it in with the values you have there.

Comment: What have you attempted? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Now i placed my code